# Process Time in R

Tags: r, time, proc

I am designing an algorithm and is trying to see how much time does each step of this takes in R and how much time does total process takes. To get the time information I use the proc.time() command. It seems that time of each step for all iteration does not match with the total time. Let me give an example for better illustration:

```
t0 <- proc.time()
for (i in 1 :100){
     t1<- proc.time()
     step 1 
     t1 <- proc.time() - t1

     t2<- proc.time()
     step 2 
     t2 <- proc.time() - t2
 }
 t0 <- proc.time() - t0
```

So, now if I add all t1 and t2 of 100 iterations, we see that this time is less than t0 or Mathematically,

```
(t1 + t2) for 100 steps < t0
```

What is the reason for above behaviour? and how can we get rid of this behaviour as this affects the runtime of algorithm drastically.

Comment: How different are they?

Comment: so, I am running this iteration for 28000 times with almost 10 steps in it, and for each iteration the amount of time varies and in the run which I made, the t1, t2, t3 ... t10 for 28000 iteration added 7 hours where as t0 was 13 hours. So, almost extra 6 hours, which I would say is huge

Comment: As Livius says, if you just add up the last values of t1, t2 and there's large variations, it's likely to be wrong

Comment: I'd recommend tearing your algorithm apart and running `microbenchmark` on `step1` and `step2` independently.

Answer (score 3):

There's a better way to time in R for performance metrics: `system.time()`. (See http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/system.time.html)

In your example, your `t0` is measuring the total time for the 100 iterations, but `t1` and `t2` are being calculated per iteration, so at the end, they only reflect the value of the time for the last iteration.

Comment: I will try using system.time().  No, it will not be the value of last iteration, because I am storing the value of t1 and t2 for all the iteration and at the end, I am adding the values of t1 and t2 for all the iteration to get the final time.

Comment: @Pawan `t0` will also have other things in it: garbage collection, scheduling overhead if you're doing something with one of the parallel packages, etc. Storing all of the individual `tn` values is also wasteful in terms of memory, potentially leading to more garbage collection or additional allocations, which can increase your run time in all sorts of ways, especially on a system without lots of RAM. The more efficient way is to get average performance is to just add them every time: `tn_running <- tn_running + tn_thisloop` and then at the end just divide by the number of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the answer for difference in total time versus the sum for all iteration of all steps. The difference was because I was using `rm()` to remove the variable and other data which will not be used in steps ahead and once these objects were deleted I used `gc()` to free up the memory. And I never measured time for `rm()` and `gc()` steps thinking that, they will not take much of time, but I was wrong, these two statements ended up taking almost same amount of time that was required for each iteration. When I removed these two, the total run time matched with the sum for all iteration of all steps. From code perspective, it can be explained as

```
t0 <- proc.time()
for (i in 1 :100){
     t1<- proc.time()
     step 1 
     t1 <- proc.time() - t1
     t01 <- proc.time()
     rm(obj1, obj2 )
     gc()
     t01 <- proc.time() - t01 
     t2<- proc.time()
     step 2 
     t2 <- proc.time() - t2
 }
 t0 <- proc.time() - t0
```

so, previously I was comparing, `sum(t1 + t2)` `for all iteration` with `t0` and obvisouly the two were not equal. Now when I compared, `sum(t1 + t2 + t01)` with `t0` and found that the two were equal. So, we can say that the difference was because of removing of object and garbage collection.
But now I have different question, why `rm()` and `gc()` takes so much of time?